# Rich calendar not rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a jsf datatable in one of my screen where I have take the date input. Hence I want to replace the input text with rich:calendar. Can someone tell me what all changes have to be done for this?

here is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
<title> Tracker</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h3>list</h3>

<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{userMB.entriesRecords}"
        var="entryRecord">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{entryRecord.entry.date}"
                rendered="#{entryRecord.editable}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{entryRecord.entry.date}"
                rendered="#{not entryRecord.editable}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </h:column>     
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Save All Changes" action="#{userMB.saveAll}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `h:inputText` with

```
    <rich:calendar enableManualInput="true"
        id="entryDate"
        datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
        value="#{entryRecord.entry.date}"
        label="Entry Date">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </rich:calendar>
```

It was tested with rich:dataTable and rich:column in RichFaces 4.3.

Comment: When I replace the  h:datatable with rich:datatable nothing is rendered. I feel that none of the rich components are rendered. I followed the steps in richfaces 3.3 getting started [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html) but still no luck. By the way I am using richfaces 3.3.4

Comment: Why you want to edit data in datatable? It think it is better to open new page or popup for editing selected row. In that moment it works fine and not related to datatable. I have this mechanism in all my applications (doesn't matter in RichFaces 3.3 or 4.3).

Comment: That's the requirement, I want to edit it on the same table. I think it should be possible.